# Unable to release batch statement

Tags: hibernate, batch-processing

I'm trying to do batch update/insert.

Here is the code.

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        //Transaction tnx =null;
        try {
            session.getTransaction().begin();
            // insert new records
            if (container.getInsertMenuItems() != null && container.getInsertMenuItems().size() > 0) {
                List<ProductSub> listOfProductSubToInsert = container.getInsertMenuItems();
                session = processTransaction(listOfProductSubToInsert, batchSize, session);
            }
            // update existing records
            if (container.getUpdateMenuItems() != null && container.getUpdateMenuItems().size() > 0) {
                List<ProductSub> listOfProductSubToUpdate = container.getUpdateMenuItems();
                session = processTransaction(listOfProductSubToUpdate, batchSize, session);
            }
            // update existing records
            if (container.getDisableMenuItems() != null && container.getDisableMenuItems().size() > 0) {
                List<ProductSub> listOfProductSubToDisable = container.getDisableMenuItems();
                session = processTransaction(listOfProductSubToDisable, batchSize, session);
            }

            session.getTransaction().commit();
            //session.getTransaction().commit();
            //session.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             System.out.println();
             if(session.getTransaction().isActive() || session== null) session.getTransaction().rollback();
        //  session.getTransaction().rollback();
            //return false;
            throw new MenuException(50001, "xxxx");

        } finally {

            session.close();

        }
```

However, I get the exception in the following method at `session.flush()` line.

```
private Session processTransaction(List<ProductSub> listOfProductSub, int batchSize, Session session) {
        int i = 0;
        for (ProductSub productSub : listOfProductSub) {
            System.out.println("name\t" + productSub.getName());
            session.saveOrUpdate(productSub);

            i++;
            if (i % batchSize == 0) {
                // flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
                session.flush();
                session.clear();
            }
        }

        return session;
    }
```

Here is the stack trace.

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute batch
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.addToBatch(BatchingBatch.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3281)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3183)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3525)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at com.abcdef.service.ProductSubServiceImpl.processTransaction(ProductSubServiceImpl.java:889)
    at com.abcdef.service.ProductSubServiceImpl.save_aroundBody14(ProductSubServiceImpl.java:853)
    at com.abcdef.service.ProductSubServiceImpl$AjcClosure15.run(ProductSubServiceImpl.java:1)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:59)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:65)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:63)
    at com.abcdef.service.ProductSubServiceImpl.save(ProductSubServiceImpl.java:827)
    at com.abcdef.menuupdate.models.OperateItem.handleUpdate(OperateItem.java:69)
    at com.abcdef.menuupdate.layers.ProductLayer.processLayers(ProductLayer.java:43)
    at com.abcdef.menuupdate.layers.ProductLayer.processLayers(ProductLayer.java:39)
    at com.abcdef.menuupdate.layers.ProductLayer.processLayers(ProductLayer.java:39)
    at com.abcdef.webapi.controllers.MenuController.runMenuUpdate(MenuController.java:122)
    at com.abcdef.webapi.controllers.MenuController.operateMenu(MenuController.java:149)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1654)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.write(IOBuffer.java:1805)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter.flush(IOBuffer.java:3581)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter.writePacket(IOBuffer.java:3482)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter.endMessage(IOBuffer.java:3062)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:6120)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatementBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1284)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtBatchExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1209)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1173)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:123)
    ... 99 more
```

I have set the hibernate propety batch size 30 and passe the same value to the method.

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="30" />
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you able to execute single entity insert/update? Looks like there is a problem with JDBCConnection.

Comment: Yes when we run the junit test, it works. However, when in the spring web application, I get the above error.

Comment: for junit test, we used JNDI